# How to set dropdownlist in tag php for loops

Tags: php, html, for-loop, drop-down-menu

When I set the option value inside of the HTML, it works:

```
<select name="month" id="month" style="width: 110px;" required>
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="">Month</option>
    <option value="01"<?= $month == '01' ? 'selected="selected"' : '';?>>January</option>
    <option value="02"<?= $month == '02' ? 'selected="selected"' : '';?>>February</option>
<Select>
```

But I don't know how to do the same thing inside of a PHP loop: (wrong)

```
<?php
    $row = 31;
    echo "<select name='day' id='day' style='width: 90px;' required>";
    echo "<option selected='selected' disabled='disabled' value=''>Tanggal</option>";
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $row; $i++) {
        echo "<option value=".$i." ". $day == $i ? 'selected="selected"' : ''.">".$i."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
?>
```

When I inspect the element, the output is:
**<1<2<3<4.....** 
Help me to set **selected='selected'** inside for php

Comment: for ($i = 1; $i <= $row; $i++) {
  if($day == $i){ $attr = 'selected="selected"';} else {$attr = '';};
        echo "<option value='".$i."' ".$arrt.">".$i."</option>";
    }

Answer (score 2):

You can better split the logic part like so:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $row; $i++) {
    echo "<option value=" . $i . " ";
    if ($day == $i) {
        echo 'selected="selected"';
    }
    echo ">".$i."</option>";
}
```

This makes it work and more readable

Answer (score 0):

It seems your logic is okey, but you need parentheses in your if like this:

```
echo "<option value=".$i." ". ($day == $i ? 'selected="selected"' : '').">".$i."</option>";
```